# It's a google hashcode 2020 task, I just have a little problem that I can't fix

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, python-itertools, hashcode

The question is, why isn't it working and just printing me a blank space. I have tried to change it several times but nothing helps. I have tried to change it into a string. Googled what can use instead of pop() didn't find anything really useful. Help please

```
from itertools import combinations 

mn = list(map(int, input().split()))

M,N = mn[0],mn[1]

arr = list(map(int, input().split()))


for L in range(0, len(arr)+1): 

      for subset in combinations(arr, L): 

            while subset:
               subset = list(subset)
               num = subset.pop()
               diff = mn[0] - num
               if diff in subset:
                 print([num, diff])
```

## It's a google hashcode2020 task

User inputs 17 number of pizza pieces and 4 types of pizza
Then he inputs 2 5 6 8 pieces of each type of pizza
Now I want my code to print me the maximum number of combinations from(2 5 6 8) and the numbers that make this maximum number(It should be 16 -> 2 + 6 + 8)

Comment: The thing is that is not working. When I run it, it gives me just a blank space.

Comment: yeah because your example doesn't satisfy the condition `if diff in subset`. Test with input: 7 4 and then 2 5 6 8